Wrong YAML syntax for github actions

Trying out github actions to auto publish an npm package but its showing these errors I don't know what's wrong. I have used my own name and email in the code instead of this dummy data shown in the attached screenshot. And yes I have already set the secret value NPM_PUBLISH_TOKEN.
#.github/workflows/auto-publish.yml
- uses: actions/setup-node@v3
  with:
    node-version: '16.x'
    registry-url: 'https://registry.npmjs.org'

- name: Bump version & push
  run: |
    git config --global user.name 'Automated publish'
    git config --global user.email 'naeem-gg@users.noreply.github.com'

    # Update the version in package.json, and commit & tag the change:
    npm version patch # YMMV - you might want the semver level as a workflow input

    git push && git push --tags
    
- run: npm publish
  env:
    NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_PUBLISH_TOKEN }}


The workflow definition is missing a few required elements. Please see below.

trigger is required - on: - I added a push trigger to main and master as I do not know your default branch
permissions are optional but I added them here because by default a workflow can access a repo as read-only.
Checkout step is also optional but because you are pushing changes, you need to checkout the repo

I did not edit the shell script as I am not sure what specific files you want to add before you commit and push.
#.github/workflows/auto-publish.yml
name: auto-publish

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
      - master

permissions:
  contents: write

jobs:
  auto-puplish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '16.x'
          registry-url: 'https://registry.npmjs.org'

      - name: Bump version & push
        run: |
          git config --global user.name 'Automated publish'
          git config --global user.email 'naeem-gg@users.noreply.github.com'

          # Update the version in package.json, and commit & tag the change:
          npm version patch # YMMV - you might want the semver level as a workflow input

          git push && git push --tags

      - run: npm publish
        env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_PUBLISH_TOKEN }}

